# php ifelse keep run else statement

Tags: php, sql, if-statement

I hava make a booking classroom function
i wanna echo a statement if user book a classroom which is already booked.
I test it to see if the ifelse statement work but the SQL INSERT inside ELSE{} run once after IF{}
I dont know why and cant find what is the mistake

```
$class=$_POST['class'];
            $time=$_POST['time'];
            $date=$_POST['date'];
            $type=$_SESSION['type'];

            $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM classroom");
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
            {
                if ($row['name']==$class && $row['date']==$date && $row['time']==$time) 
                {

                    echo "The class at this time already been booked.";
                }
                else
                {
                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO classroom(name,date,time,bookedby) VALUES('$class','$date','$time','$type')");                 
                    if ($_SESSION['username']=='admin') {
                    mysql_query("UPDATE classroom SET status='yes' WHERE name='$class' AND date='$date' AND time='$time'");                 
                    }
                    echo "booking submitted";
                    break;
                }

            }
```

Comment: Your code checks to see if each row matches, and for each row that doesn't, inserts a new row. You want to check if _any_ row matches, and if _none_ do, insert a new row.

Comment: first off, use mysqli or PDO with prepared statements, two: just use a select where statements, you can't loop that in PHP and compare each row, thats just not intuitive, three just add a condition before insertion, no need to insert then update

Comment: ok i got it...thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic you used is not correct. Try this code instead.

```
        $class=$_POST['class'];
        $time=$_POST['time'];
        $date=$_POST['date'];
        $type=$_SESSION['type'];

        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM classroom where name='$class' && date='$date' && time='$time'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0)
        {
                 echo "The class at this time already been booked.";
        }
        else
        {
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO classroom(name,date,time,bookedby) VALUES('$class','$date','$time','$type')");                 
                if ($_SESSION['username']=='admin') {
                mysql_query("UPDATE classroom SET status='yes' WHERE name='$class' AND date='$date' AND time='$time'");                 
                }
                echo "booking submitted";
                break;


        }
```

I just modified your code. It's better to learn usage of mysqli/pdo and replace the usage of mysql since it is deprecated.

Also it's better to change the column name 'date' to something else since date is a predefined mysql keyword. Even though it is not included in the reserved words and mysql permit usage of 'date', my opinion is not to use it since it may cause confusions and also some conflicts in some cases returning error.

Comment: mysql_num_rows returns the total number of selected rows. If it's greater than zero (>0) it means there are rows satisfying the condition. Which means some on else has already booked the class room.